# Getting pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@Id".')

Tags: python, sql, selenium, sql-server-2016

I am trying to execute .sql file from Python3.
Below is the python code I am trying

```
import time
userdate=time.strftime("%m_%d_%H_%M%S")
import pypyodbc as pyodbc
db_host='hostname\DBTEST'
db_name='dbname'
conn='Driver={SQL Server};Server=' + db_host + ';Database=' +db_name + 
';Trusted_Connection=yes;'
db=pyodbc.connect(conn)
cursor=db.cursor()
file=open('C:\\abc\\xyz.sql','r')
line=file.read()
sql_cmd=line.split('\n')
for x in sql_cmd:
   cursor.execute(x)
```

Below is the xyz.sql script

```
DECLARE @XML XML;
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
SELECT @Id = NEWID()
SELECT @FileName = 'ggg.xml' 
SELECT @XML = '<Model>
    ....xml tags here...
    ....        

</Model>'

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tablename CM WHERE CM.columnname = 'test') BEGIN
    UPDATE CM
        SET CM.pn = '01-00001',
            CM.rev= '06',
            CM.Model = @XML,
            CM.ModifiedOn = GETUTCDATE()
       FROM cm.tablename CM
       WHERE CM.columnname= 'test'

    PRINT 'Updated ' + @FileName
END ELSE BEGIN
    INSERT INTO cm.tablename(cmID, MN, CMType, Description, PN, Rev, CM, 
    RowStatus, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn)
    SELECT @Id, 'test123', 'abc.1', '', '01-00011', '01', @XML, 'A', 
'74E8A3E0-E5CA-4563-BD49-12DFD210ED92', GETUTCDATE()
    PRINT 'Inserted ' + @FileName
END
```

I get below error when I run the python code.

```
pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL 
Server Driver][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@Id".')
DECLARE @XML XML;
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
SELECT @Id = NEWID()
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Note: If I run the sql query from M/S SQL Management studio (sql server 2016), it runs successfully.
any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Some of your `DECLARE` and `SEELCT` lines end with semi-colons, others don't.  Try using semicolons more consistently and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the input.
lines1=line1.replace('\n', ' ') seemed to do the trick. I did takeout semi-colons as well since they were not needed.
file = open('C:\\abc\\xyz.sql', 'r')
line = file.read()
lines = line.replace('\n', ' ')
cursor.execute(lines)

Comment: Getting the above "replace" kludge to work was rather lucky, see my answer for a much simpler & safer approach.  The "replace" kludge is unsafe because it can set you up for surprises later (imagine what happens if you had accidentally used an empty string to replace the line terminator - a hard-to-spot error).  Also, note that the SQL isn't being executed one line at a time (which won't work anyway, see my answer). Instead cursor.execute is being called exactly once and is passed the entire (modified) query.  BTW, semi-colons as a cause of the problem is almost certainly a red herring.

Comment: Strike "won't work anyway" from my comment.  My concern was out-of-scope errors; I've since discovered that (SQL) scoping is done on a connection basis, not on a "cursor.execute"  basis, which means that using cursor.excute on a line-by-line basis won't cause scoping issues.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to NOT execute the script one command at a time, I instead use the simpler approach of passing the entire query to cursor.execute as one **unedited** script.

The great thing about doing it this way is you can fully develop/debug the query in MS Sql Server and then just copy that procedure into a file (making the simple adjustments for passing arguments of course).

As a (python 3.x, with pyodbc) example, I use:

```
SQL_QueryName  = SQL_Folder + AllAreasReportName + ".sql"
Textfile = open( SQL_QueryName, 'r' )        
SQL_COMMANDS = Textfile.read()

cursor.execute( SQL_COMMANDS, ParameterList )
```

The same approach should work with pypyodbc.

BTW,  if the query must appear within the python procedure, put the entire query inside a (triply quoted) string and pass that string to cursor.execute.